# Page Content not Appearing

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using a menu bar from this tutorial: http://css-tricks.com/learning-jquery-fading-menu-replacing-content/

When I replaced the content with my own, it does not load it. I'm putting in a slider with images and when I click one of the buttons it will not load it for some reason.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<title>Menu Fader from CSS-Tricks</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>

<!--CONTENT SLIDER-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/basic-jquery-slider.css">
<script src="../js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/basic-jquery-slider.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){

        $("#page-wrap div.button").click(function(){

            $clicked = $(this);

            // if the button is not already "transformed" AND is not animated
            if ($clicked.css("opacity") != "1" && $clicked.is(":not(animated)")) {

                $clicked.animate({
                    opacity: 1,
                    borderWidth: 5
                }, 100 );

                // each button div MUST have a "xx-button" and the target div must have an id "xx" 
                var idToLoad = $clicked.attr("id").split('-');

                //we search trough the content for the visible div and we fade it out
                $("#content").find("div:visible").fadeOut(1, function(){
                    //once the fade out is completed, we start to fade in the right div
                    $(this).parent().find("#"+idToLoad[0]).fadeIn();
                })
            }

            //we reset the other buttons to default style
            $clicked.siblings(".button").animate({
                opacity: 0.5,
                borderWidth: 1
            }, 100 );

        });
    });

</script>

<style>
.container {
width: 100%; left: 0; right: 0; top:0; bottom: 0; position: fixed; overflow: auto;
background-image:url(../images/screen.png);
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<div id="page-wrap">

<div id="menu">
<img src="../../Website/images/logo.png" />
    <div id="home-button" class="button">
        <img src="../images/menu-home.png" alt="home" class="button" />
    </div>
    <div id="about-button" class="button">
        <img src="../images/menu-about.png" alt="about" class="button">
    </div>

    <div id="contact-button" class="button">
        <img src="../images/menu-contact.png" alt="contact" class="button">
    </div>

    <div id="gallery-button" class="button">
        <img src="../images/menu-gallery.png" alt="gallery" class="button">
    </div>

    <div id="affiliates-button" class="button">
        <img src="../images/menu-affiliates.png" alt="affiliates" class="button">
    </div>

    <div id="bio-button" class="button">
        <img src="../images/menu-bio.png" alt="bio" class="button">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div id="content">

        <div id="home">

<div id="container">
  <div id="banner">
    <ul class="bjqs">
      <li><img src="../images/banner02.jpg" title="Cool Skull"></li>
      <li><img src="../images/banner04.jpg" title="Women1"></li>
      <li><img src="../images/banner01.jpg" title="Kid With Shell"></li>
      <li><img src="../images/banner03.jpg" title="Women2"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

        </div>

        <div id="about">
            <p>This content is for about.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="contact">
            <p>This content is for contact.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="gallery">
            <p>This content is for contact.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="affiliates">
            <p>This content is for contact.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="bio">
            <p>This content is for contact.</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You might have better luck on the css-tricks forum. Probably more chance someone's had the same problem there. http://css-tricks.com/forums/

Comment: obvious question... that author notes that article has been deprecated. Have you looked at his/her new link?

Comment: Have you inspected the errors using Firebug or other web inspectors? That probably could give you more info as to why your code didn't work. Most likely it's some JS error.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a semi-colon.

I added the semi-colon and a comment so you knew where it was.  Hope that fixes it!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<title>Menu Fader from CSS-Tricks</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>

<!--CONTENT SLIDER-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/basic-jquery-slider.css">
<script src="../js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/basic-jquery-slider.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){

        $("#page-wrap div.button").click(function(){

            $clicked = $(this);

            // if the button is not already "transformed" AND is not animated
            if ($clicked.css("opacity") != "1" && $clicked.is(":not(animated)")) {

                $clicked.animate({
                    opacity: 1,
                    borderWidth: 5
                }, 100 );

                // each button div MUST have a "xx-button" and the target div must have an id "xx" 
                var idToLoad = $clicked.attr("id").split('-');

                //we search trough the content for the visible div and we fade it out
                $("#content").find("div:visible").fadeOut(1, function(){
                    //once the fade out is completed, we start to fade in the right div
                    $(this).parent().find("#"+idToLoad[0]).fadeIn();
                }); //THIS ; WAS MISSING.
            }

            //we reset the other buttons to default style
            $clicked.siblings(".button").animate({
                opacity: 0.5,
                borderWidth: 1
            }, 100 );

        });
    });

</script>

<style>
.container {
width: 100%; left: 0; right: 0; top:0; bottom: 0; position: fixed; overflow: auto;
background-image:url(../images/screen.png);
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<div id="page-wrap">

<div id="menu">
<img src="../../Website/images/logo.png" />
    <div id="home-button" class="button">
        <img src="../images/menu-home.png" alt="home" class="button" />
    </div>
    <div id="about-button" class="button">
        <img src="../images/menu-about.png" alt="about" class="button">
    </div>

    <div id="contact-button" class="button">
        <img src="../images/menu-contact.png" alt="contact" class="button">
    </div>

    <div id="gallery-button" class="button">
        <img src="../images/menu-gallery.png" alt="gallery" class="button">
    </div>

    <div id="affiliates-button" class="button">
        <img src="../images/menu-affiliates.png" alt="affiliates" class="button">
    </div>

    <div id="bio-button" class="button">
        <img src="../images/menu-bio.png" alt="bio" class="button">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div id="content">

        <div id="home">

<div id="container">
  <div id="banner">
    <ul class="bjqs">
      <li><img src="../images/banner02.jpg" title="Cool Skull"></li>
      <li><img src="../images/banner04.jpg" title="Women1"></li>
      <li><img src="../images/banner01.jpg" title="Kid With Shell"></li>
      <li><img src="../images/banner03.jpg" title="Women2"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

        </div>

        <div id="about">
            <p>This content is for about.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="contact">
            <p>This content is for contact.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="gallery">
            <p>This content is for contact.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="affiliates">
            <p>This content is for contact.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="bio">
            <p>This content is for contact.</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```